# How to use filter search in angular chart?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I'm using angular chart in my ongoing project. And I want to use a dropdown filter search according to months in angular chart for user convenience. Is it possible?
Here's my code:

```
app.controller('newController',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.labels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
    $scope.series = ['Expenses', 'Invoices', 'Proposals'];
    $scope.data = [
        [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90],
        [50, 20, 10, 35, 70, 1, 100]
    ];
}])

<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options" chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride" chart-click="onClick" style="height: 185px; width: 339px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Months or year wise?

Comment: months...like from january to september

Comment: but there is no data to filter1

Comment: oops my bad. ok lets do it for year. i just want the concept how to do it. Like from 2007 - 2009

Answer (score 1):

Angular charts is watching the data bound to it, so you can use angular filters on the attributes.

Build a custom filter that takes 2 arguments, and filters the array.

```
function isBetween(from, to) {
    return function(val) {
        return val >= from && val <= to;
    }
}
```

Now assuming the function `isBetween` is bounded to the `$scope`, you can use:

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels|filter:isBetween(2007, 2009)" chart-series="series" chart-options="options" chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride" chart-click="onClick" style="height: 185px; width: 339px;"></canvas>
```

Change the hard-coded values with values from a dropdown or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do using the angular.foreach.

Here is a **DEMO**

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp', ['chart.js'])

  .controller('myController', [function() {
   
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.newlables = [];
    ctrl.applydata = function(){
      angular.forEach(ctrl.socialChart.labels,function(val){
         if(val > ctrl.socialChart.fromyear && val < ctrl.socialChart.toyear){
           ctrl.newlables.push(val);
         }
        ctrl.socialChart.labels = ctrl.newlables;
      });
      
    }
    ctrl.socialChart = {
      fromyear :'',
      toyear:'',
      type: 'Bar',
        labels: ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'],
        series:['Expenses', 'Invoices', 'Proposals'],
        colors: ['#ED402A', '#F0AB05', '#A0B421', '#00A39F'],
        data : [
        [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90],
        [50, 20, 10, 35, 70, 1, 100]
    ]
    }
      ctrl.filtervalues = ctrl.socialChart.labels;
     
  }]);

})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Multi Slot Transclude</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-chart.js/1.0.3/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as ctrl">

  <select ng-model="ctrl.socialChart.fromyear" ng-options="o as o for o in ctrl.filtervalues">
  </select>
  <select ng-model="ctrl.socialChart.toyear" ng-options="o as o for o in ctrl.filtervalues">
  </select>
  <canvas id="outreach" class="chart chart-bar" chart-labels="ctrl.socialChart.labels" chart-data="ctrl.socialChart.data" chart-series="ctrl.socialChart.series" chart-colors="ctrl.socialChart.colors" chart-options="ctrl.socialChart.options"></canvas>

<button ng-click="ctrl.applydata()"> Filter</button>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: do you have github repo or stackblitz for above in Angular 6?